# error: C compiler cannot create executables while cross compile tcpdump

Tags: compiling

when I cross compile tcpdump for the rt-ac86u from the https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin.ng repository using the https://github.com/RMerl/am-toolchains toolchain, tested on a x86_64 Ubuntu host:

1.clone the asuswrt-merlin.ng repo, change directory to `release/src/router/tcpdump-4.4.0`,then:

```
CC=aarch64-linux-gcc AR=aarch64-linux-ar RANLIB=aarch64-linux-ranlib AS=aarch64-linux-as LD=aarch64-linux-ld NM=aarch64-linux-nm ac_cv_linux_vers=2 CFLAGS=-static CPPFLAGS=-static LDFLAGS=-static ./configure --host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu && make
```

It occurs the error:

> configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
>
> See `config.log' for more details

And the log shows:

> ./configure: line 2704: aarch64-linux-gcc: command not found

Since I am new for compiling, so does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for your kindly replying!!!!!

Comment: We don't support generic GNU/Linux, and you've given no OS/release details

Comment: Do you have the package (gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu) that provides that executable) installed?